Magento 2.4.7 Compile Error With Core BrainTree Module - Solution? - Fixed Using php 8.3
Running Magento 2.4.7 on Nexcess, php 8.1. though I tried with 8.2 as well. Non Issue With php 8.3!
Compile error:
[servername]$ php bin/magento setup:di:compile
Compilation was started.
Repositories code generation... 1/9 [===>------------------------]  11% 1 sec 117.0 
MiBPHP Fatal error:  Null can not be used as a standalone type in 
/servername/vendor/paypal/module-braintree-core/Plugin/DeleteStoredPaymentPlugin.php 
on line 57


I use Adobe Payment Services, but not BrainTree or PayPal directly and could happily shut it down for now to get past this. My site is down. I tried turning off every PayPal and BrainTree module I could find, but it didn't fix the problem.
- Magento_PaymentServicesPaypalGraphQl
- Magento_Paypal
- Magento_PaypalCaptcha
- Magento_PaypalGraphQl
- Magento_ReCaptchaPaypal
- Magento_PaymentServicesBase
- Magento_PaymentServicesDashboard
- Magento_PaymentServicesPaypal
- Magento_PaymentServicesSaaSExport
- PayPal_Braintree
- PayPal_BraintreeCustomerBalance
- PayPal_BraintreeGiftCardAccount
- PayPal_BraintreeGiftWrapping
- PayPal_BraintreeGraphQl

The code at Line 57 of that module:
    public function beforeDelete(
        PaymentTokenRepositoryInterface $subject,
        PaymentTokenInterface $paymentToken
    ): null {


Thoughts to get me compiled back up and running?

I'm having this issue too, did you get it resolved? I'm Magento 2.4.7 on Nexcess, php 8.1 too

I did not get it resolved, however I spoke with My Adobe Payment Services Rep and Tech Support person. They encouraged me to open a ticket which I need to do (should have that done by tomorrow). From there, they can work with APS, PayPal and Braintree to investigate and resolve.

are you upgrading from 2.4.6-p5? Do you see this line in var/log/debug.log when you di:compile?
Source class "\Magento\ServiceProxy\Model" for "Magento\ServiceProxy\Model\Logger" generation does not exist.

you need to speak to Nexcess and get them to update composer to 2.7 quote my ticket number 18147110 if you want. Hope that helps

I didn't get a moment to check if I saw that issue in the debug.log - only compile error. Once I hit that, I stopped - since I couldn't fix that myself.... Will the composer update also fix this issue? How are they related? Certainly happy to get composer up to latest in any case (thanks for that ticket #) - and would love to have them get NewRelic updated as well - surprised that's not been updated in quite a while. Although I should add that I've been very happy with Nexcess. The LiquidWeb merger has added a lot of non-Magento support folks, but that's to be expected.

no idea how compiling and composer being out of date are related apart from when you update composer then run composer update it updates some more modules. I'd agree Nexcess are very good

Gotcha - I keep my Magento system updated weekly or more often depending, but having composer updated as well would be nice. I just looked and saw they're on 2.3.10. Not sure that what what issues that might be causing (if any). but I notice that NewRelic complains of their back-version. But that Braintree bug (one line of code!) is a real problem.....

So now that I upgraded the site to php 8.3 and too the time to add each PayPal and BrainTree module back in one by one, the issue is no longer present... no idea if this was specifically an 8.1 issue, but it's no longer a problem. Issue closed.

Not checked  how to disable paypal/braintree, but this should only occur when trying to compile Magento 2.4.7 under PHP 8.1. The stand-alone type null was introduced with PHP 8.2.

It looks like the only way to disable Braintree is to disable all of PayPal's extensions (something like 9 or 10 of them). Happily, the Adobe Payment Services team also helped me go through my site and found a number of other things to clean up, so the entire adventure was a bonus.

We are having the same issue in a dev environment preparing to update from 2.4.6 to 2.4.7.
It appears that the beforeDelete method is part of a plugin implementation for the PaymentTokenRepositoryInterface. As noted in comments on line 51 the purpose of this plugin is to delete the payment method token from Braintree before deleting it from Magento.
To resolve the issue, we removed the return type declaration (: null) from the beforeDelete method signature (below)
In the updated code, the beforeDelete method no longer has a return type declaration.
I was able to successfully compile after making this update and that's all I was hoping to do. As we too do not use Braintree.
vendor\paypal\module-braintree-core\Plugin\DeleteStoredPaymentPlugin.php
<?php
/**
* Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
* See COPYING.txt for license details.
*/
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace PayPal\Braintree\Plugin;

use Exception;
use PayPal\Braintree\Model\Adapter\BraintreeAdapter;
use Magento\Vault\Api\Data\PaymentTokenInterface;
use Magento\Vault\Api\PaymentTokenRepositoryInterface;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class DeleteStoredPaymentPlugin
{
private const BT_PAYMENT_METHOD_CODES = [
'braintree',
'braintree_paypal',
'braintree_applepay',
'braintree_googlepay',
'braintree_venmo',
'braintree_ach_direct_debit'
];
/**
* @var BraintreeAdapter
*/
private BraintreeAdapter $braintreeAdapter;

/**
* @var LoggerInterface
*/
private LoggerInterface $logger;

/**
* DeleteStoredPaymentPlugin constructor
*
* @param BraintreeAdapter $braintreeAdapter
* @param LoggerInterface $logger
*/
public function __construct(
BraintreeAdapter $braintreeAdapter,
LoggerInterface $logger
) {
$this->braintreeAdapter = $braintreeAdapter;
$this->logger = $logger;
}

/**
* Delete the payment method token from the Braintree before deleting it from Magento
*
* @param PaymentTokenRepositoryInterface $subject
* @param PaymentTokenInterface $paymentToken
* @return void
*/
public function beforeDelete(
PaymentTokenRepositoryInterface $subject,
PaymentTokenInterface $paymentToken
) {
try {
if (!in_array($paymentToken->getPaymentMethodCode(), self::BT_PAYMENT_METHOD_CODES)) {
return;
}

$token = $paymentToken->getGatewayToken();
$this->braintreeAdapter->deletePaymentMethod($token);
} catch (Exception $e) {
$this->logger->error($e->getMessage());
}
}
}


Thanks for this solution for all of us non-BrainTree users, @Xander! Just curious - what php version are you on?

Using PHP Version 8.1. Composer version 2.7.6
We did temporarily switch to PHP 8.3 to see if doing that would resolve the issue, it did not. So we switched back to PHP 8.1 and implemented the code change. We will continue to test the site.
